# Removing bathroom faucet aerator

Tags: bathroom, faucet

When I turn this bathroom faucet on and off, the water flow is somewhat irregular so I tried looking at the aerator to see if it needs cleaning:

[image: aerator]

What kind of aerator is this and how do I remove it?

It doesn't look like any of the aerators that I can find by searching the web. I'm not sure what manufacturer made this faucet as it has no labels on it. I tried to put a screwdriver in there and turning but was not able to make it move. Do I need a tool specifically for this aerator?

Viewed from above:

[image: Viewed from above]

Comment: that only shows the end-on view ... please add a side view

Comment: @jsotola I've added another picture. It's completely smooth, there's no part of the faucet that can be taken apart.

Comment: shine a light inside the end of the tap ... there may be a screw

Comment: @jsotola Good idea! Unfortunately no luck, there doesn't seem to be anything behind the white plastic.

Comment: If you don't have a special adjustable  "spanner" wrench I'd insert needle nose pliers into holes in the plastic and turn. You could make a spanner with a liece of wood and two nails protruding from it the right distance apart to fit into holes in the plastic grille. You might be able to slip two nails into the grille and then clamp them in the jaws of needle nose locking pliers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure what kind of aerator this is but I was able to remove it.

After keeping the tip of the faucet soaked in a small bag of vinegar for a couple of hours, I was able to turn the aerator with a screwdriver but it didn't really feel like it was coming out. The plastic was also brittle and started breaking apart when I tried turning it, so eventually it came out when it broke apart. It looks like this is simply a plug since there appears to be no threading in the faucet.

[image: aerator removed]

I'm going to have to see if I can find some kind of replacement for this that will fit in an unthreaded faucet.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. Please give yourself a check-mark so others know this one is resolved.

Comment: @FreeMan I've marked it as checked although I don't think the answer I posted really answered the original question well. I haven't been able to find a replacement aerator yet.

Comment: Well, the question was "how do I remove the aerator", not "where do I find a replacement". ;) Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Well if you read the question in it's entirety it's actually about what kind of aerator it is and what tool is required to remove it. Perhaps the title should have been more clear about this. I didn't exactly figure out what tool to use to remove it either since it broke apart when I tried the suggestion given in the comments. Technically I was able to remove it but I think it was clear from the context that I was looking for a method or tool that would not break it.